# @strongify(self.delegate) not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, reactive-cocoa

About `@weakify` and `@strongify` when using `self` and `self.delegate`

I receive:

> /WAMOverviewView.m:306:10: Weak property 'delegate' is accessed multiple times in this method but may be unpredictably set to nil; assign to a strong variable to keep the object alive

I tried to use `@strongify(self.delegate)` or`@strongify(self->_delegate)`
but I receive:

> WAMOverviewView.m:304:16: Redefinition of 'self' with a different type: 'id _Nullable __strong' vs 'WAMOverviewView *const __strong'

Any idea or suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Apart from that, in other parts of the program I tried to use 
`@strongify(self, self.delegate)` but doesn't work.
Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

Don't use @strongify. It's pointless. Just assign the delegate to a strong variable. Safe yourself the bother and unnecessary reliance on third party tools.

Comment: I think weakify/strongify makes our code easier to read, that is the reason I want to use it.